# Unable to add decimal like 0.25 with EditText Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an app with **editText** and I want to insert **decimal numbers** that start from (0.25-0.50-0.75 and so on) because I want to calculate it with other editText numbers, till now I can only insert numbers like 1-2-3...
Any idea please?

> MyCode

```
price_per_piece.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!s.toString().equals("")) {
                    //case_qty = v.findViewById(R.id.et_add_item_case_quanitiy); this line for understanding
                    //Note : case_qty is EditText which i want to insert decimal numbers
                    String qty_txt = case_qty.getText().toString();
                    if (qty_txt.equals("")){
                        qty_txt = "1";
                       // qty_txt = "0.25";
                    }
                    float qty = Float.parseFloat(qty_txt);
                    float p = Float.valueOf(s.toString());
                    price_per_case.setText(String.valueOf(qty * p));
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @RMPR i already added

Comment: Did you try to add android:inputType="numberDecimal" instead of "number"?

Comment: @RakshitNawani yes i tried it's inserted but when i calculate it gives me error

Comment: What kind of error you are getting, try to use Double.parseDouble(s.toString()) to convert your string into a decimal format

Comment: @RakshitNawani samething 
The error is

 > E/Volley: [486] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://vendtapwebapp.azurewebsites.net/api/items/postitem

Comment: @MohammedQadah This is not the error related to your code, this is related to the Volley API request, either some error from server-side or internet issue in your device

Comment: @RakshitNawani I found the answer Thanks for your help

Comment: Happy coding cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` to your EditText xml declaration if you have not done so already. Then try use `Double.parseDouble()` instead of the float